# Apply a function on a DataFrame that depend on the previous row values

Tags: pandas

I want to detect max and min of a time series, always looking on the left side. Looking right would be looking in the future since it's analyzed in live.
My method:

- When increasing, you update the variable `max`
- When decreasing, you update the variable `min`
- Then, when decreasing, if the value is inferior to 50% of `(max - min)`, you
  consider that you are defining a new low
- And vise versa when increasing

It translates like this:

```
import pandas as pd

timerange = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/31/2018')
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, -2, -4, 0, 5, 3, 2, 0]
timeseries = pd.DataFrame(index=timerange, data=data, columns=['Value'])

max = data[0]
min = data[0]
pct = .5
tendancy = False
for now in timeseries.index:

    value = timeseries.loc[now, 'Value']

    if value >= max:
        max = value
    if value <= min:
        min = value

    range = max-min

    # Cancel the previous max value when going up if the 50% rule is triggered
    if value >= min + range * pct and tendancy != 'up':
        tendancy = 'up'
        max = value
    # Cancel the previous min value when going down if the 50% rule is triggered
    elif value <= max - range * pct and tendancy != 'down':
        tendancy = 'down'
        min = value

    ratio = (value-min)/(max-min)

    timeseries.loc[now, 'Max'] = max
    timeseries.loc[now, 'Min'] = min
    timeseries.loc[now, 'Ratio'] = ratio

timeseries[['Value', 'Min', 'Max']].plot()
timeseries['Ratio'].plot(secondary_y=True)
```

It works as expected and as a result, looking at the `Ratio` variable, you know if you are currently defining a new low (0) or a new high (1), whatever the amplitude or the frequency of the signal.

However, on my real data (~200 000 rows), it is super long. I was wondering if there is a way to optimize this, especially using the `.apply()` method of DataFrame. But since results depend on the previous row, I don't know if this method is applicable.

Comment: It's a bad practice using keywords `max,min, range` as variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and easy speed up you can do is instead of iterating over the index and accessing each time with `loc`, is to iterate over the value directly and append into a list the three results (`max-, min-, ratio-`) you want like:

```
max_ = data[0] #NOTE: I rename the variables with _ to avoid using builtin method names
min_ = data[0]
pct = .5
tendancy = False
l_res = [] # list for the results
for value in timeseries['Value'].to_numpy(): #iterate over the values

    if value >= max_:
        max_ = value
    if value <= min_:
        min_ = value

    range_ = max_-min_

    # Cancel the previous max value when going up if the 50% rule is triggered
    if value >= min_ + range_ * pct and tendancy != 'up':
        tendancy = 'up'
        max_ = value
    # Cancel the previous min value when going down if the 50% rule is triggered
    elif value <= max_ - range_ * pct and tendancy != 'down':
        tendancy = 'down'
        min_ = value

    ratio = (value-min_)/(max_-min_)
    # append the three results in the list
    l_res.append([max_, min_, ratio])

# create the three columns outside of the loop
timeseries[['Max', 'Min','Ratio']] = pd.DataFrame(l_res, index=timeseries.index)
```

In terms of timing, I put both ways in functions (f_maxime for yours and f_ben for this one) and it gives:

```
%timeit f_maxime(timeseries)
# 16.4 ms ± 2.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit f_ben(timeseries)
# 651 µs ± 17.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

so this way is about 25 time faster, and for 200K rows, I think it should still be 25x time faster. Also I checked that the result is the same:

```
(f_ben(timeseries).fillna(0) == f_maxime(timeseries).fillna(0)).all().all()
#True
```

regarding the use of `apply`, I don't think there is any value in this case for speeding up the code, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

Comment: Works great, and thanks for the documentation on the `apply` method, I learnt a lot

Comment: @Maxime I have tried to vectorize it, but the `if...elif...` part seems difficult to make it this way.  If you really need another level of speedup, I suggest you have a look at Numba, but it is another library :)

Comment: It's been several times I heard about this library, I'll have a look. Thanks!